# Jetbrains Rider WPF Design Time Data

Tags: wpf, jetbrains-ide, design-time, rider

I'm working at a WPF Project and want to use Rider.

I recognized that the preview in Rider dosen't support Design Time Preview.

Everything having a *d:* infront will be completley ignored by the Preview.
I tried it on diffrent Computers, Versions and Projects, so I doubt that it is a bug.

Are there any Plugins or workarounds for rider you know of?